# Updating only SQLite database file of application without replacing application code and other files on air

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing an android application with inbuilt SQLite database. I need to replace SQLite database file only every 3 months. while doing this I should not alter any part of code.

Also I don't want to do this as upgrading application where changing app version I can replace old application with newer version and new database.

For example if I give a button "Update Database" and after clicking this button only database file is replaced using internet and other parts of application remains intact.

Comment: For clarity... So you're looking at seperating the SQLite code as much as possible from the application code so that one can be changed w/o affecting the other, correct?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply...possibily yes...but i need to replace only database file.

Answer (score 1):

simply do as you'd do with any file:

1. Download the database file from a web server to the devices temp directory (or cache or SDCard)
2. Move that file to your application's data directory

To do that automatically, you should use a service started by the AlarmManager.

Comment: Thanks MarvinLabs.I will check this solution.